# How can i slow down the zoom scroll effect level in d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3js.
I am using d3.zoom to zoom into the stage with the mouse scroll wheel and the problem i am facing is that the zooming effect was too noticeable / quick?
I want a finer scroll wheel effect , so that for the user to zoom in to their desired extent they have to scroll more and the zooming effect is less significant.I dont want the user to zoom in or zoom out more, but i want them to have a finer control of their zoom level?

```
   d3.select(svgRef)
      .call(
        d3
          .zoom()
          .scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
          .on("zoom", zoomed)
          .filter((event) => {
            return event.ctrlKey;
          }),
        d3.zoomIdentity.scale(0.5),
      )
```

```
const zoomed = (data: any) => {
// In case data.transform is undefined, use d3.zoomIdentity instead where k = 1, x = y = 0
const transform = data.transform || d3.zoomIdentity;
// Translate x, y coordinates if zooming
console.log(data.sourceEvent.deltaY, "deltaY");
if (data.sourceEvent.deltaY) {
  // Calculate the scale change
  const scaleDelta = Math.pow(2, data.sourceEvent.deltaY * 0.001);

  // Get the cursor position in the SVG coordinate system
  const cursorPosition = d3.pointer(data.sourceEvent, svgRef);

  // Calculate the new translate and scale values to zoom around the cursor position
  const newTranslateX =
    transform.x - (cursorPosition[0] - transform.x) * (scaleDelta - 1);
  const newTranslateY =
    transform.y - (cursorPosition[1] - transform.y) * (scaleDelta - 1);
  // Apply the new transform values
  const newTransform: any = d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(newTranslateX, newTranslateY)
    .scale(transform.k * scaleDelta * 0.8);

  // Update the transform and zooming level of g tag with transform-zoom class
  d3.select(svgRef)
    .selectAll("#links-container, #nodes-container")
    .attr("transform", newTransform);
  setZoomingLevel(newTransform.k);


  // Toggle subtitle rect display based on zoom scale
  if (newTransform.k >= ZOOM_LEVEL) {
    d3.select(svgRef)
      .selectAll("[data-subtitle-rect='true']")
      .style("display", "block");
  } else {
    d3.select(svgRef)
      .selectAll("[data-subtitle-rect='true']")
      .style("display", "none");
  }
  //change text when zoom past lvl
  //show subtile text when zoom in

  node
    .transition()
    .duration(50)
    .selectAll("[data-subtitle-text='true']") // Select the text element
    .style("display", () => {
      if (newTransform.k > ZOOM_LEVEL) {
        return "block"; // Show text when zoomed in
      } else {
        return "none"; // Hide text when zoomed out
      }
    });

  //hide parent text when zoom in if there is subtiles
  node
    .transition()
    .duration(50)
    .selectAll("[data-has-subtiles='true']") // Select the parent text element
    .style("display", () => {
      if (newTransform.k > ZOOM_LEVEL) {
        return "none";
      } else {
        return "block";
      }
    });
}
```

};

i tried to log the data.transform 's value each time i zoom , d3.interpolateZoom

[same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487020/how-to-change-speed-of-translate-and-scale-when-zooming-in-and-out-in-d3-using) this used d3.event.scale which is deprecated ? and my transform.k values varies very large( 0.5 to 1 to 6 to 10 each time i scroll)